# Convert text to date in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently I exported some data, from a database using a query in which each row for a "comment" column begins with a date formatted as MM/DD/YY.

I used the `=LEFT(TEXT,8)` function to only extract the date but it happens that the some of the dates are formatted inconsistently so we may have some that are M/D/YY where the month or day isn't two digits, this will then include a ';' as a separator since it is less than 8 characters.

Is there a way I can format the text so the ';' is excluded? That way I can sort the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `DATEVALUE` function does most of what you need.  It takes in many different date formats (M/D/YYYY, MM/DD/YYYY etc) and converts it to an excel date (i.e. # of days since 1/1/1900).

The formula below says:

- If the date is clean then just apply `DATEVALUE` function
- If there is an error, just use the part to the left of the ';'

Assuming 9/1/2013 is Cell A2:

```
Input Data      Sortable Excel Date
----------      -------------------
9/1/2013;       =IFERROR(DATEVALUE(A2),DATEVALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(";",A2)-1)))
09/2/2013;      9/2/2013
10/1/2013;      10/1/2013
10/10/2013      10/10/2013
```

I've made a live Excel sample [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10791482/Sample_ConvertTextToDate.xlsx).

Comment: +1 Good use of DateValue and for including a live demo... might not work for user if they can't format that cell as a date.  i.e. Their output is part of a larger string.

Comment: Good to hear from another Portlander :-).  True about the cell format, though you could replace every instance of `DATEVALUE` with `TEXT(DATEVALUE(...),"MM/DD/YYYY")`.  The formula is getting pretty muddled by then though, so another alternative might be better.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your text looks like this:  ;1/;2/13  or 1/2/13;;  or ;;1/2/13

You can use substitute like this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,";","")
```

The result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So if date is either the first 6, 7 or 8 characters of A2 you can get the date with this formula

`=LOOKUP(10^10,LEFT(A2,{6,7,8})+0)`

format result cell in required date format

As the result is a valid date you can sort these as you would sort numbers